# Common value for set of numbers

Tags: java

I need to show common value for set of numbers like below

```
0 for 0-99
100 for 100-199
200 for 200-299 and keep going,
```

how can i achieve this?

I can't get the values, because i don't know the algorithms

Comment: What do you mean by "common value"?

Comment: Please describe the input and the desired output. If you have tried anything so far, post the code here. Otherwise please try something and post it here.

Comment: Given a number `x`, I believe you are looking for `x - (x % 100)`. This takes away the ones and tens digits from the number in question.

Comment: i mean i need to show the output, if i pass any number in a function , output will be a common number for 0-99, 100-199 like this.
> 100  -  100
> 200  -  200
> 300  -  300


fun calFine(74);  // Output 0
fun calFine(220);  // Output 200
fun calFine(300);  // Output 300

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
int hundredsteps(int value) {
    return (Math.round(value / 100)) * 100);
}
```

Comment: good answer, think this should work

Comment: Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing, is getting what "hundred" there is in a integer value.
In java this can be done by using a simple integer division.

The trick here is that the value is an integer. So there is no decimal: 
hundreds(199) will return 1.

```
int hundredth(int value) {
    return (value / 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the answer below

```
int getNumber(int value){
    int div = value/100;
    return div*100;
}
```

Explanation.
 If value = 74 than div = 0 and div*100 = 0, output is 0

 If value = 67 than div = 0 and div*100 = 0, output is 0

 If value = 122 than div = 1 and div*100 = 100, output is 100

 If value = 150 than div = 1 and div*100 = 100, output is 100

 If value = 221 than div = 2 and div*100 = 200, output is 200

Comment: This is what i want, Thank you ...

Comment: happy to see if you upvote

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow , already upvoted , my reputations below 15.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the very classic way:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    int n = 130;

    if (n < 100) {
        System.out.println(0);
    } else if (n < 200) {
        System.out.println(100);
    } else if (n < 300) {
        System.out.println(200);

    // add more range steps here

    } else {
        System.out.println("infinity");
    }
}
```

This will output `100` for `int n = 130;`, go test some values of your input set.

> What I don't get is your use of the term *common value*, because the output is not really common, but the smallest number in the range.

**Please Note** that this will get uglier the more ranges you want to check. Consider using the answer given by Andy Nopparat AnyNope Bui.

Comment: Yeah,  I got the answer, anyway thank you for your response